# Why is brew trying to install a dependency that is already installed?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, python

Why does brew attempt to download a dependency (and fail) when that dependency is already installed?

I'm trying to install a python bottle from homebrew on a system that does not have Internet access.

```
brew reinstall --debug --verbose --skip-cask-deps build/deps/python-3.11.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
```

The above command fails when brew tries (and fails) to access the Internet to download one of the dependencies (`mpdecimal`)

```
==> Fetching dependencies for python@3.11: mpdecimal, ca-certificates, openssl@1.1, readline, sqlite and xz
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FromDefaultNameLoader): loading mpdecimal
==> Fetching mpdecimal
/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --config /Users/maltfield/sandbox/buskill-app/build/deps/.curlrc --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.2.11\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.15.7\)\ curl/7.64.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --location --silent --head https://www.bytereef.org/software/mpdecimal/releases/mpdecimal-4.0.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://www.bytereef.org/software/mpdecimal/releases/mpdecimal-4.0.0.tar.gz
/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --config /Users/maltfield/sandbox/buskill-app/build/deps/.curlrc --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.2.11\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.15.7\)\ curl/7.64.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --location --silent --head https://www.bytereef.org/software/mpdecimal/releases/mpdecimal-4.0.0.tar.gz
/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --config /Users/maltfield/sandbox/buskill-app/build/deps/.curlrc --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.2.11\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.15.7\)\ curl/7.64.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --remote-time --output /Users/maltfield/sandbox/buskill-app/build/deps/downloads/72a206df09e9c8bd3f7b24b1dc25e15971fb05aab8c1576b95b73df2ae463ca0--mpdecimal-4.0.0.tar.gz.incomplete --location https://www.bytereef.org/software/mpdecimal/releases/mpdecimal-4.0.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 1000 milliseconds
Error: Failed to download resource "mpdecimal"
Download failed: https://www.bytereef.org/software/mpdecimal/releases/mpdecimal-4.0.0.tar.gz
```

However, when I check the system, I see that `mpdecimal` is already installed. In fact, all of the dependencies are all already installed!

```
bash-3.2$ brew list | grep -iE 'mpdecimal|ca-certificates|openssl|readline|sqlite|xz'
ca-certificates
mpdecimal
openssl@1.1
readline
sqlite
xz
bash-3.2$
```

Why is brew trying to fetch a dependency that's already installed, and how do I tell it to stop trying to do that (or, at least, proceed with installing the bottle anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

Check the version with `brew list --versions` and you can update your formula cache to prevent it from updating

### Why?

By default `brew list` doesn't show you the versions installed. Add `--versions` to see that

```
bash-3.2$ brew list --versions | grep -iE 'mpdecimal|ca-certificates|openssl|readline|sqlite|xz'
ca-certificates 2022-10-11
mpdecimal 2.5.1
openssl@1.1 1.1.1q
readline 8.2.1
sqlite 3.39.4
xz 5.2.7
bash-3.2$
```

In this case, you can see that you have `mpdecimal 2.5.1` installed, but the output from the `brew reinstall` above shows that its trying to download `mpdecimal 4.0.0`.

#### Fix it

This is terrible and I only figured it out by trial-and-error, but apparently brew doesn't try to install the version required by the bottle (I couldn't see that defined anywhere in the bottle itself) -- but it just tries to download the latest version based on the formulas you have cached on your system.

The homebrew formulas are a collection of `.rb` files stored in Homebrew's `homebrew-core` github repo:

- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/

On your system, this repo is checked-out by Homebrew here:

```
maltfield@host m % ls -lah /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
total 120
drwxr-xr-x   17 maltfield  admin   544B Mar 30 23:19 .
drwxr-xr-x    5 maltfield  admin   160B Mar 30 23:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x   15 maltfield  admin   480B Mar 30 23:19 .git
drwxr-xr-x    8 maltfield  admin   256B Mar 30 23:19 .github
drwxr-xr-x  277 maltfield  admin   8.7K Mar 30 23:19 Aliases
-rw-r--r--    1 maltfield  admin   1.4K Mar 30 23:19 CODEOWNERS
-rw-r--r--    1 maltfield  admin   5.5K Mar 30 23:19 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x   29 maltfield  admin   928B Mar 30 23:19 Formula
-rw-r--r--    1 maltfield  admin   1.3K Mar 30 23:19 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 maltfield  admin   479B Mar 30 23:19 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   20 maltfield  admin   640B Mar 30 23:19 audit_exceptions
drwxr-xr-x    5 maltfield  admin   160B Mar 30 23:19 cmd
-rw-r--r--    1 maltfield  admin   5.3K Mar 30 23:19 formula_renames.json
-rw-r--r--    1 maltfield  admin    20K Mar 30 23:19 pypi_formula_mappings.json
drwxr-xr-x    9 maltfield  admin   288B Mar 30 23:19 style_exceptions
-rw-r--r--    1 maltfield  admin   2.4K Mar 30 23:19 synced_versions_formulae.json
-rw-r--r--    1 maltfield  admin   1.1K Mar 30 23:19 tap_migrations.json
maltfield@host m %
```

Fortunately, if you already have the dependencies installed (Homebrew installs them to `/usr/local/Cellar`, then you can just overwrite these `.rb` files with the ones that you have installed, and it will make `brew reinstall` skip the attempt to download updates to the depends.

In my case, for the python-3.11 bottle, I executed the following

```
maltfield@host ~ % cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/m
maltfield@host m % mv mpdecimal.rb mpdecimal.rb.$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
maltfield@host m % cp /usr/local/Cellar/mpdecimal/*/.brew/mpdecimal.rb .
maltfield@host m % 

maltfield@host ~ % cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/c
maltfield@host c % mv ca-certificates.rb ca-certificates.rb.$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
maltfield@host c % cp /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/*/.brew/ca-certificates.rb .
maltfield@host c % 

maltfield@host c % cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/o
maltfield@host o % mv openssl@1.1.rb openssl@1.1.rb.$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
maltfield@host o % cp /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/*/.brew/openssl@1.1.rb .
maltfield@host o % 

maltfield@host o % cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/r
maltfield@host r % mv readline.rb readline.rb.$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
maltfield@host r % cp /usr/local/Cellar/readline/*/.brew/readline.rb .
maltfield@host r % 

maltfield@host r % cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/s
maltfield@host s % mv sqlite.rb sqlite.rb.$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
maltfield@host s % cp /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/*/.brew/sqlite.rb .
maltfield@host s % 

maltfield@host s % cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/x
maltfield@host x % mv xz.rb xz.rb.$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
maltfield@host x % cp /usr/local/Cellar/xz/*/.brew/xz.rb .
maltfield@host x %
```

Now attempting to install the python bottle works, without failing at trying to download depends that are already installed.

For more info, see:

- https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/issues/78#issuecomment-2028484207